# Objective C sort NSArray using class member function

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm have an NSArray that I need to sort based on variables that are stored inside an object (in this case my class name is SchedView which is a UIViewController).  I was thinking NSArray would let me pass it a "member function" (not sure if that is the term used in Objective-C or not, I'm new to this language).  It appears I can only pass a static/C style function though, so this is what I ended up with:

```
- (NSInteger) BuildGridSortCompare :(id) r1 :(id) r2 :(void*) context
{
    // Have compare code here, and can use class scope variables...

    return NSOrderedSame;
}

NSInteger _BuildGridSortCompare(id r1,id r2,void *context)
{
    SchedView *sv = (__bridge SchedView*) context;
    return [sv BuildGridSortCompare:r1 :r2 :NULL];
}

- (void)BuildGrid
{
    Records = [Records sortedArrayUsingFunction:_BuildGridSortCompare context:(__bridge void *)(self)];
}
```

BuildGrid and BuildGridSortCompare are member functions of my SchedView class (selectors?).  _BuildGridSortCompare is basically a C style function that is just a wrapper to call my member function.

I've used this design before in C/C++ code, but not in modern platforms such as Java and C#, so thought maybe Objective-C might have a better way?

I'm not real sure about some of the typecasts as well, the __bridge mostly.

Is what I am doing safe, or is there another function similar to sortedArrayUsingFunction that lets me use a member function?  I did see sortedArrayUsingSelector, but that appears to call a function on the class I am sorting.  In this case I want the function to be implemented by self.

Comment: what type are the elements of your array?

Comment: Custom class I defined that derives from NSObject.

Comment: The class itself does not know all of the sort criteria though, that is why I want the sort function to be external -- not self contained like I would do if the criteria was something simple like an alpha sort.  It is a complex scheduler interface and records are sorted based on selected users, number of days in the view, start/end times, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is OK, but you can do this much more elegantly using *blocks*:

```
records = [records sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    // compare code here, can use self etc.
    return ...;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this, but the examples looked messy.  Seeing it the way you have it makes it look clean, I will change to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok.  I find more useful though to sort an array in iOS using either of those two methods:

1. `sortedArrayUsingSelector`: this imply you pass a selector as parameter. If you use this you can use a selector on a comparison method that already exist on the type of your array. For example if you have an array of NSNumber you can pass @selector(compare) this will call the compare method on your NSSNumber object. You might need to implement your own compare-method for your object if this is not a predifine type.
2. `sortedArrayUsingComparator`: this imply you pass a block as parameter which i think is more shiny.

Comment: Is it possible to use sortedArrayUsingSelector, and give it a selector that comes from [self] instead of from the class type contained in the array?  If so, I would probably use that method over the answer I accepted, but I don't think it is possible.

Comment: what is the type of the element in ur array?

Comment: the method you pass in your selector is a method that preexist or you have define on the class your element in array belongs to